# change text displayed when ion button is toggled

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am trying to change the text displayed from go online to go offline when i toggle the ion-toggle button in my ionic app. Here is my html code

```
 <ion-label color="light" *ngIf="!isOnline">Go Online</ion-label>
    <ion-label color="light" *ngIf="isOnline">Go Offline</ion-label>


  <ion-toggle (ionChanges)="updateDriverOnlineStatus($event)" [checked]="isOnline"></ion-toggle>
```

Here is my typescript file

```
public isOnline: boolean = false;


updateDriverOnlineStatus($event)
  {
  this.isOnline = !this.isOnline;
  }
```

How can i go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the event name to `ionChange` instead of `ionChanges`:

```
<ion-toggle 
  (ionChange)="updateDriverOnlineStatus($event)" 
  [checked]="isOnline">
</ion-toggle>
```

Also, you can do this with just one:

```
<ion-label color="light">{{ isOnline ? 'Go Offline' : 'Go Online' }}</ion-label>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-toggle-eg?file=pages/home/home.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the name of the event from `ionChanges` to `ionChange` :

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="updateDriverOnlineStatus($event)" [checked]="isOnline"></ion-toggle>
```